# Deleting an item with condition in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I want to remove a product from the Cart by checking its quantity. Its quantity should be decremented by 1 unless it reaches zero, and after that, it should pull out from the product array of the Cart.

here is my Logic : (I want to perform the pull and decrement operation inside the single query. But I m stuck on how to perform these two operations together by a simple condition in MongoDb)

```
const cart = await Cart.findOneAndUpdate({"products.productId": req.body.productId}, {$inc: {"products.$.quantity": -1}}, {new: true})
         
await Cart.update({"products.productId": req.body.productId}, {$pull: {quantity: 0}})
```

here is the model for clarification:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const cartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    products: [
        {
            productId: {
                type: String,
            },
            quantity: {
                type: Number,
                default: 1
            }

        }

    ]
    
}, {timestamps: true});
const Cart = new mongoose.model('Cart', cartSchema);

export default Cart;
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight way to do this in single regular update query.

To improve your approach you can try this,

- first query to check `productId` and `quantity` should greater than 1

```
const cart = await Cart.updateOne(
  { 
    products: {
      $elemMatch: {
        productId: req.body.productId,
        quantity: { $gt: 1 }
      }
    }
  }, 
  { $inc: { "products.$.quantity": -1 } }
);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1fRu_6nRGKa)

- second query if the first query's result is `nModified` is 0 then pull the product, by checking condition `productId` and `quantity` equal-to 1

```
if (cart.nModified === 0) {
  await Cart.updateOne(
    { 
      products: {
        $elemMatch: {
          productId: req.body.productId,
          quantity: { $eq: 1 }
        }
      }
    }, 
    { $pull: { products: { productId: req.body.productId } } }
  )
}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nUSg7tAC0az)

---

If you really want to do using single query you can try [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- `$map` to iterate loop of `products` array and check condition, if the `productId` matches then increment/decrement `quantity` by `$add` operator otherwise return current quantity
- `$filter` to iterate loop of above result and check condition if `productId` and `quantity` is not zero

```
await Cart.updateOne(
  { "products.productId": req.body.productId },
  [{
    $set: {
      products: {
        $filter: {
          input: {
            $map: {
              input: "$products",
              in: {
                productId: "$$this.productId",
                quantity: {
                  $cond: [
                    { $eq: ["$$this.productId", req.body.productId] },
                    { $add: ["$$this.quantity", -1] },
                    "$$this.quantity"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          cond: {
            $and: [
              { $eq: ["$$this.productId", req.body.productId] },
              { $ne: ["$$this.quantity", 0] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5Jgf52WYj8S)